# Running java application from android project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is it possible to run a java porgram which does some simple operations like may be just perform addition,subtraction,etc from a android project in eclipse? When I do so, I get the following error.
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=15848, tid=47842905868608
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_45-b18) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /rhel5pdi/workplace/golchham/android-amazon/src/MAAAndroidSampleAPK/hs_err_pid15848.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Any help on this ?I found similar errors but all were with some memory related or library issues. I don't find any here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to just copy the code over or are you porting it into Androids Activity system?

Comment: How exactly did you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the std JRE to "properties / java build path / libraries"

In the "runconfiguration / classpath" remove Android (leaving only std JRE)

[Classfile err](http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/16/solved-internal-error-classfileparser-cpp3161/)

[Internal error](http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/17/worked-out-why/)